Is falsifiability precision, knowability, or both?
I have sometimes heard people say that there is merit in formulating claims that are “falsifiable”.
I can imagine that “falsifiable” means “can be falsified”, and “falsified” means “judged, determined, or shown to be false”.
This is an interesting concept. It seems to imply that even if something is true, it could be false. I can imagine that one epistemic viewpoint might argue that this does not make sense, because if something is true, it cannot be false.
One interpretation I can think of for what this epistemic prescription is saying, is that utterances should be ‘precise’. From the perspective of model theory (I think), the fewer models a formula has, the more precise it is.
For example, consider an empty signature, {}. I believe (I need to check) that all the formulae that can be written over the empty signature have either the empty set as a model, or are modeled by every structure.
For example, the formula “for all x, it is not the case that x equals x” has only the empty set as its model; whereas the formula “for all x, x equals x” has every set as a model.
The empty formula also has every structure as a model. I would say that the empty theory is not very precise, because it is a statement which holds true for every possible interpretation.
On the other hand, there are theories with a unique model. I’m not sure, but I feel like there could be a rigorous definition for precision, just in that “there is only one possible meaning of this sentence”.
However, does this reflect Popper’s “apothegm”? I’m actually not sure to say “This sentence has only one structure which satisfies it” is the same as to say “this sentence is precise”. In some ways, we could say that every sentence of first order logic is perfectly “precise”, because, for the most part, it can be decided if a structure models it or not.
This leads me to another thought, where falsifiability is more related to the logical idea of ‘decidability’, or to the concept in modal logic of ‘knowability’, making use of a “known” operator K.
So, for the time being, I open this question:
First, we find ourselves in a world of knowledge and communication that we did not create, and whose rules we do not fully know. We may observe that some utterances differ from other utterances; but in what ways? One might say in precision, or in falsifiability, or in other ways, but these are intuitions lacking, as of yet, clear definitions.
Let’s say we say “falsifiable” means “could be shown to be false”. What examples might there be of this? If I say, “My bedsheets are olive green”, prior to it being determined as true or false, it sounds determinable. But determinable in what way? Partially, on a practical level: one could enter my bedroom, and see for oneself. But also determinable on a deeper level, perhaps - there is something about the form of the utterance which sounds unambiguous in meaning; that clearly, in any conceivable world, so long as I have a bed with sheets on it, and the color olive green exists, (and there is some kind of stable object persistence?), it seems necessary that the utterance is either true or false, regardless of whether or not we currently know the answer.
This is just the opening to a more developed question, hopefully. But, what might lend support to the prescription “Sentences should be falsifiable”? When we say “should”, what modal base is this: ‘should’ for what end? And is ‘falsifiable’ an inherent property of the form of an utterance - within a context of a particular language - or is it much more contingent on the world we live in, the access we have to information about the world, or the possible (alternative, or maybe even counterfactual) worlds enabled in our local understanding of “possible worlds”, within our world? (Are “possible worlds” relative to the world one is in?)

Assuming you’re logically consistent in the sense of the usual classic or intuitionistic logics, how can you claim “even if something is true, it could be false.” in the beginning of your question which is already a very precise formal statement of your proposed (first order) theory?…

Appearance and reality.  Something that appears to be true can be false.  The idea of absolutely certainty is appealing,  but not very tenable.

Popper's definition of falsifiable is "capable of conflicting with possible, or conceivable observations". It is not much different from defining "soluble in water" as "capable of dissolving when placed into water". If something is true, it cannot be false, but it could be false. One interprets the "could" as they usually interpret subjunctive mood in the given context. In philosophical jargon, subjunctive sentences are called counterfactuals and they are well-studied.

Popper's notion of falsifiability is a defense of science against Hume's argument that we can't possibly verify that a law of nature is true. An enormous amount of the philosophy of science is focused around Hume's argument. The argument (adapted specifically to scientific laws) is basically this: how can we know that a law of nature, say L1, is true? We can't observe that L1 is true because we can only observe a set of instances and that doesn't prove that the law is true in general. So the only way we can infer from a set of finite experiments to L1 is if we have some general law of nature, let's call it L2, that tells us when we can infer from a set of experiments that a law of nature is true. But how do we know that L2 is true? Go back to the beginning and you have an infinite regress.
Popper's solution is to admit that Hume is right and that there is no way to verify a law of nature, so he claims that science is not in the business of verifying laws. Instead, science comes up with the best possible explanation, and the job of science is then to try to falsify a law. A law is a universal statement so although it cannot be verified without observing every single instance ever, it can be falsified by observing a single instance where it is not true.
Falsification doesn't have any of the logical or epistemological implications you suggest. It is just the idea that it only takes a small number of experiments to prove that a general law is false (it only takes one if you can be sure your observations are always correct). A law is falsifiable if there is an experiment that can prove that it is false. It is unfalsifiable if there is no experiment that can prove that it is false.
There are many problems with Popper's theory of falsification, and most uses of the term in popular arguments about science are misuses. For example, it has been shown by many examples that science in fact almost never accepts a falsification of a theory until they have a better theory to use. There are always ways to dodge around the falsification: claiming experimental error, claiming misapplication of the theory to the experiment, and minor modifications of the theory to avoid the experiment are much more common responses. And in fact, most scientists act like they do believe their theories have been verified.

I haven't read much Popper, but "science in fact almost never accepts a falsification of a theory until they have a better theory" because the moral claim that "the job of science is [...] to falsify" doesn't match the moral claims of scientists, which is that their job is to do their job. Which is to provide value to their employer (possibly themselves) - while being employed make or test the best possible predictions about the outcomes of measurements, not declare victory and go home upon discovering that they can't make perfect predictions.

...add 'or teach the techniques to do the same' to my last sentence above, to include professors.
